# RETAIN VARIABLE & Initialise 0 SAS- Use case scenario

Tags: variables, initialization, retain

`````
    I am very new to SAS & request help to understand use case of 'Retain' function, below are 2 codes where end goal is cumulative height to be added in new column 'Tot_Height', using 2 different codes, however both give same result, hence confused when would retain function be used and variable be initialised as 0 ?????
    Data Set [Data Set][1] : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt1j6.png)
    Code No 1
```
        data class3;
        set class2;
        retain tot_height 0;
        by sex;
        if first.sex then tot_height = Height;
        else tot_height + Height;
        run;
````
    Code No 2
````
        data class3;
        set class2;
        if first.sex then tot_height = Height;
        else tot_height + Height;
        run;
````
`````

Please help understand from above 2 codes as i am confused where would retain help

Comment: Did you run the two data steps? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference between those two steps because of the use of the SUM statement in the ELSE clause.

The SUM statement has the form:

```
variable + expression ;
```

The result is that the value of EXPRESSION is added to the value of VARIABLE.  And that VARIABLE is defined to be RETAINed and if there is no other RETAIN statement with an explicit initial value it is initialized to zero.  So adding the explicate RETAIN statement in the first data step that is setting the initial value to zero does not change how the data step will work.

Normally on each iteration of the data step variables that are created by this step (as opposed to variables that are coming from input datasets) will be set to missing.  The RETAIN statement says to NOT set them to missing so the value at the start of on iteration is the same as it had at the end of the previous iteration.

Note that for these data steps the initial value is immediately overwritten by the first value of HEIGHT for the first observation since by definition the first observation in the dataset is the first observation of a BY group.  So even if you were to change the initial value in the RETAIN statement to something other than zero it will have no real effect since it will be immediately replaced.

Comment: Also i tried 2 different approaches, pls see
Code 1 / Result : Output is same, even after adding 1000 in retain nothing changes

data class3;

`set class2;
retain tot_height 1000;
by sex;
if first.sex then tot_height = Height;
else tot_height =tot_height + Height;
run;`

Code 2 / Result : All values in tot_height column are missing

`data class3;
set class2;
if first.sex then tot_height = Height;
else tot_height =tot_height + Height;
run;`


i am curious how and where would retain function work and where it can be skipped

Comment: Thank you @Tom for the detailed answers, i tried inputting different values to the retain function eg 100 , 1000 etc but it did nothing, so i am wondering why did my instructor ask me to use the retain function, i had asked him if it doesnt make any difference in the output whats the use for the same, he just said its a best practice, When you mention "if there is no other RETAIN statement ....it is initialised to zero" does that mean there needs to be 2 different retain statements otherwise the first retain statement will just retain the variable but not use the value (0 in this case)

Comment: I tried another 2 approaches

Code 3 / Result : works

`DATA CLASS7 (KEEP= COUNT SEX TOT_WEIGHT);
SET CLASS4;
RETAIN TOT_HEIGHT 0;
BY SEX;
IF FIRST.SEX THEN TOT_WEIGHT=WEIGHT;
ELSE TOT_WEIGHT+WEIGHT;
IF LAST.SEX;
RUN;`

Code 4 / Result : Doesnt work

`DATA CLASS7 (KEEP= COUNT SEX TOT_WEIGHT);
SET CLASS4;
IF FIRST.SEX THEN TOT_WEIGHT=WEIGHT;
ELSE TOT_WEIGHT+WEIGHT;
IF LAST.SEX;
RUN;`

Comment: Change the SUM statement to a normal assignment statement `tot_weight=sum(tot_weight,weight);` and then the RETAIN statement is required.  Teacher is probably correctly assuming that more people understand RETAIN than understand SUM statements.

Comment: To see the effect of the initial value you need to remove the IF FIRST.SEX test that is overwriting the initial value.  That will create a running sum over the the whole class instead of just one gender.